# HTML5 Canvas blurry when zoomed in on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, antialiasing

I'm writing a game similar to the famous https://www.reddit.com/r/place/. I have a `1000x1000` canvas where I use `drawImage()` function to populate the canvas. My setup is like this:

```
<div id="container"><canvas/></div>
```

and I manage the zooming part using the following CSS rule:

```
$("#container").css({ transform: `scale(z)`});
```

where `z` represents the zoom level and I change it depending on user input

I have `imageSmoothingEnabled = false` on my canvas context. ***This works fine*** on desktop, however on mobile when I zoom in, the pixels are blurry. I'm guessing this has to do with `devicePixelRatio` but I couldn't figure it out. I also have:

```
image-rendering: pixelated; 
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
```

in my CSS for the canvas.

- Here is a screenshot from desktop/chrome when zoomed:

[image]

- Here is a screenshot from mobile(ios) when zoomed:

[image]

The pixelation issue only manifests itself on mobile when zoomed in.